# Issue with Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have an issue with Gravity Forms, the wordpress theme the website is using is Kallyas. The form doesn't seem to use the CSS anymore and it also stopped submitting info when I input something. Can anyone help me figure this out? I'm new to wordpress and Gravity Forms, the website has been created by someone else but I don't have any contact with that person.

Gravity Forms support forums recommends to check if Output Default CSS is turned on, it should be on and it is. I'm not sure what else to try :(